# Noresize automatic in Firefox (ala wikipedia cache)?

Tags: firefox

When I load [this webpage](http://wikiwix.com/cache/?url=http://www.mediapart.fr/journal/france/280508/des-juges-contournent-la-loi-pour-utiliser-des-tests-adn-ethniques&title=http://www.mediapart.fr/journal/france/280508/des-juges-contournent-la-loi-pour-utiliser-des-tests-adn-ethniques) in Firefox I get all the text displayed in only one page, which is great!

However when I reach [this one](http://www.mediapart.fr/journal/france/280508/des-juges-contournent-la-loi-pour-utiliser-des-tests-adn-ethniques) (the same URL but the beginning) I get five pages to click (see red rectangle) + 1 more click so I can also read the comments ("commentaires" see in yellow).

[image]

Can anyone help me use the noresize HTML function (the same used apparently in Wikipedia's cache) automatically in Firefox for the website mediapart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the complete article, [disable Javascript](http://mistered.us/tips/javascript/firefox.shtml)

Comment: Hello "mobe",
Well, many thanks. ;) 
I am now using this addon in Firefox and it does the job. ;)
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/210517/
Thank you again ;)